Cube.js Real-time Data Issue - First API Call Stale Data
I’m working with Cube.js for real-time transaction reporting and facing a data freshness issue. We’ve set the refresh_key.every parameter to 1 second to ensure the latest data on every API call. However, the first API call consistently returns stale data, with the actual data appearing only on subsequent calls.
Here’s my question:
Is there a way to guarantee fresh data on the very first API call using Cube.js with a 1-second refresh key?
Are we potentially making a configuration error, or is this a known behavior with Cube.js caching?
Additional Context:
We’re using Cube.js for reporting and listing transaction data in our product.
We’ve verified the refresh_key.every parameter is set to 1 second.
I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community to achieve real-time data on the first API call.
